# Exponential function to the power of a fraction

Tags: exponential-function, exponential-sum

I have an equation such that

$$1=e^{\frac{ylog(3+x)}{3+x}}-3 -x$$

Where e is the exponential function. How do I solve for x?

According to the laws of exponents, $a^{m/n}=\sqrt[n]{a^m}$,

Applying this that would leave me with,

$$1=e^{\frac{ylog(3+x)}{3+x}} =\sqrt[3+x]{e^{ylog(3+x)}}$$

Does this mean that I can simplify the expression as follow?

$${e^{ylog(3+x)-(3+x)}}$$

I'm not sure how to take it from here, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The final step is wrong. What you can do, however, is write $$e^{\frac{y\ln(3+x)}{3+x}}=\left(e^{\ln(3+x)}\right)^{\frac{y}{3+x}}=(3+x)^{\frac{y}{3+x}}.$$ Not sure how helpful that is though.

Comment: You seem to be asking whether $e^{\frac{A}{B}}=e^{A-B}$ and that's nonsense.